# Can I split a physical GPU into two virtual devices in tensorflow 2.x?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, tensorflow2.x

I would like to test using multiple GPUs for training a network. However, I only have installed one physical GPU (RTX 2070) on my machine. Would I be able to split this device into two virtual devices?
My current attempt is based on the `tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration` function, however, it does not seem to be working. Full example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__) # 2.4.1
phisical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")
print(phisical_gpus) # [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_configuration(
    phisical_gpus[0],
    [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=2048),
    tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=2048)]
)
print(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices("GPU")) # [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The total number of GPU devices visible should be verified with `list_logical_devices`:

```py
logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices('GPU')
print(logical_gpus)
#[LogicalDevice(name='/device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU'),
# LogicalDevice(name='/device:GPU:1', device_type='GPU')]
```